# Why is my component showing when i don't have it in my app.js

Tags: reactjs

Why is my component showing when I don't have it in my app.js
I want my Menu component to be on another page, but it's showing on the bottom of app.js file.

Here's my app.js
`

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Menu from './Components/Menu';
import Section from './Components/Section';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <Section />
            <Footer />

            <Routes>
                <Route path="/"></Route>
                <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu/>}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`Here's my navbar component`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link as LinkTo } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../Images/logo.png';
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';

function Navbar() {
    const navRef = useRef();

    const showNavbar = () => {
        navRef.current.classList.toggle('responsive_nav');
    };

    return (
        <>
            <nav className='full-nav' ref={navRef}>
                <img className='nav-logo' src={logo} alt='Burritos la chiquita Logo' />
                <ul style={{ listStyle: 'none', cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                    <li>
                        <LinkTo to="/menu" onClick={showNavbar}>
                            Menu
                        </LinkTo>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link
                            activeClass='active'
                            to='about'
                            spy={true}
                            smooth={true}
                            onClick={showNavbar}>
                            About Us
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link
                            activeClass='active'
                            to='Location'
                            spy={true}
                            smooth={true}
                            onClick={showNavbar}>
                            Location
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <button className='nav-btn nav-close-btn' onClick={showNavbar}>
                        <FaTimes />
                    </button>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div className='nav-container'>
                <img src={logo} alt='' srcset='' className='nav-logo' />
                <button className='nav-btn' onClick={showNavbar}>
                    <FaBars />
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

`

Here is the [image with footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qahzy.png)

The Menu component shows under the footer and now on a new webpage.

Comment: Can  you include more code or a minimal reproducable example so that community members can understand the problem better and provide proper solution as you can see members are trying their best to guess the  issue

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering footer above the routes in your app.js. You should place your routes between navbar & footer. eg.

```
 <>
        <Navbar />
        <Section />
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/"></Route>
            <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
    </>
```

Comment: I don't want it to show on the main page. I want it to link to a different webpage